# Google-maps error : Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

I having trouble with my javascript code. It has worked previously. Normaly when i click on my a href in my table i gets the coordinates of de class 'coords' in a my google maps (gmap_canvas). it has stopped working for some reason. Maybe i do something wrong, but i don't know what! Also i get the Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined in my console. Does someone know what this is?

Here you will find the html and the javascript.

```
<div class="card">
<div class="header">
    <h4 class="title">SUEZbox</h4>
</div>
<div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <th>Box</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th style="display: none">Coordinates</th>
            <th>View</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b><?php echo $box['suezbox_naam']; ?></b></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $box['user']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $box['naam']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $box['location']; ?>
                </td>
                <td class="coords" style="display: none"><?php echo $box['coordinates'];?></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)">View Location On Map</a></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

the javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var markers = [];

        function init_map() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14
                , center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.934547, 4.412453)
                , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);

            $('table tr').each(function (idx, item) {
                var coordsStr = $(this).find(".coords").html();
                console.log(coordsStr);
                if (!coordsStr) return;
                createMarker($(this));
            });
            $('.click').click(function (evt) {
                var coordsStr = $(this).parents().find(".coords").html();
                console.log(coordsStr);
                coords = coordsStr.split(",");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
                map.setCenter(point);
                google.maps.event.trigger(markers[coordsStr], 'click');
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click')
        }

        function createMarker(jqe) {
            var coordsStr = $(jqe).find(".coords").html();
            console.log(coordsStr);
            coords = coordsStr.split(",");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
                , position: point
            });
            var content = jqe.find("td").eq(0).html(); + '<br>'
            var content1 = '<strong></strong><br>' + jqe.find("td").eq(2).html(); + '<br>'
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(content + content1);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            markers[coordsStr] = marker;
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>
```

Comment: working fiddle for reference  http://jsbin.com/moriteyuve/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

syntax error :

```
var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14
                , center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.934547, 4.412453)
                , mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);

            $('table tr').each(function (idx, item) {
                var coordsStr = $(this).find(".coords").html();
                console.log(coordsStr);
                if (!coordsStr) return;
                createMarker($(this));
            });
            $('a').click(function (evt) {
                var coordsStr = $(this).parents().find(".coords").html();
                console.log(coordsStr);
                coords = coordsStr.split(",");
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
                map.setCenter(point);
                google.maps.event.trigger(markers[coordsStr], 'click');
            });
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click');


        function createMarker(jqe) {
            var coordsStr = $(jqe).find(".coords").html();
            console.log(coordsStr);
            coords = coordsStr.split(",");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map
                , position: point
            });
            var content = jqe.find("td").eq(0).html(); + '<br>'
            var content1 = '<strong></strong><br>' + jqe.find("td").eq(2).html(); + '<br>'
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infowindow.setContent(content + content1);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            markers[coordsStr] = marker;
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

Comment: You should explain and give a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This way it's difficult to understand.

Comment: might be the extra bracket after line : google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click');

Comment: Makes no differents :)

Comment: yes  @bfmags is right.
extra bracket after line : google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click');

Comment: Okay but i still get the same error in console, and the coords also not working..

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_e3' of undefined" several times. Usually it was an attempt to set event listeners on the nonexistent DOM elements.

I would suggest checking if the element exists before you try trigger the click on it. Something like:

`if(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"]) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers["52.939347, 4.754741"], 'click');
}`